# Sharing cookies across domains and subdomains

Tags: django, cookies, multi-tenant

I'm trying to implement a multi-tenancy architecture with Django and django-tenant-schemas.

I'm successfully accessing the baseapp from `http://app.mysite.com:8000/` and setting a cookie sessionId (which is http-only) when I log into the application. (Port 8000 is only for development)

I'm now trying to make a request to `http://tenant1.mysite.com:8000/accounting/`. When I inspect the request headers, however, I see that the cookies have not been set even though in my settings file I have:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mysite.com"
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".mysite.com"
```

I was under the impression that setting my cookie domain to `.mysite.com` would allow access to subdomains. What am I missing here?

Comment: You want to share the user session or some cookie value ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing django sessions on specific subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742675/sharing-django-sessions-on-specific-subdomains)

Comment: @sideffect the sessionId is stored in the cookie

Comment: If you want is sharing cookie ( not specific key ) or user session check the link above, what is your settings in SESSION_COOKIE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but just in case someone lands here wondering about a similar issue it is possible that the cookie is set but the SessionMiddleware does not find a valid session for the session id received. This could happen for example if you are using the database session backend and you happen to have put `django.contrib.sessions` in your `TENANT_APPS` list. In this case Django won't find any session because when you logged in at `app.mysite.com` the session was stored in the database schema corresponding to the `app` tenant and when you tried to access `tenant1.mysite.com` the `SessionMiddleware` looked for a session stored in the `tenant1` schema.

So the conclusion to this is, if you are using the database backend for storing sessions, then you should put `django.contrib.sessions` into your `SHARED_APPS` list and not into `TENANT_APPS` list.

Hope this helps.