# Django one login system multiple apps using postgresql

Tags: python, django, database

I want to have multiple django projects but using just one user database to login and have that instance (request.user)? I am using PostgreSQL.

I mean when I access to one app of Django still has the same cookie for login or user another app.

Comment: It depends, for example if they're on a sub-domain then you can set **session** for your whole domain to make it available in all your sub-domains. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742675/sharing-django-sessions-on-specific-subdomains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible and here are your two options

1. You need to share DB between your apps and configure Cookie

   a. To share db for USERS model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

   b. Update settings

   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN will give you access to cross-domain cookies

   ```
   SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies" 
   SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'your_cookie_name'
   SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.yoursite.com'
   SECRET_KEY = "Share same key(this key) between your apps"
   ```

   SECRET_KEY should be same in both app's settings.py
2. Try to implement Django openid, something like FB oauth login / Google oauth
   login

   Here is Django OIDC:  http://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.x/

Comment: so when i implement django openid i can share the login between django projects? i asked this because i have already 3 projects with different order of ids user (repeated) on each project, but i want to create a "master" database then with that database if an user logged in on app and change to another man the other project detect that the user has already logged in

Comment: Yes, you can share login, but the user needs to authorize the login, something like how you login to Netflix using Facebook.

Comment: i will try share a database with users only through all my django projects, thanks @naren