# Sharing Sessions on Subdomains

Tags: django

I'm trying to set up a way to have a user jump around from subdomain to subdomain.

Let's say I have the following subdomains:

one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com

If I log into, say, two.example.com, the user should be able to jump over to one.example.com or to three.example without having to log back in.

I'm following the following example:

[Stackoverflow - 3742675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742675/sharing-django-sessions-on-specific-subdomains)

... and I have my settings on both sites:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.example.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'examplesession'
```

However this is not working.  I also changed my secret key, but that's not working either.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556907/how-to-get-distinct-django-apps-on-same-subdomain-to-share-session-cookie

Comment: Do all servers point to the same session backend?

Comment: eliang:  yes, it does.